# d3 v5: How to transition only when a specific attribute changed?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I have a map with a circle at the center of each country. I apply an animation that updates the circles every 3 seconds, following the [**general update pattern**](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234) by Mike Bostock. However, my problem is that I want to apply a transition to old elements that stay in the chart (i.e. are not part of the `exit()`), but only for those that have a change in a particular attribute (because this attribute defines the color of the circle). I figured that I should store the old value as an attribute in the circle and then just compare this attribute value with the newly assigned value from the updated data.

However, when I use a usual js `if` clause it only provides me with the first element, which means when this circle's value changes, all other circles will get the transition as well.

How can I check between the old and the new value inside this pattern?

Here is a sample code:

```
//DATA JOIN                 
var countryCircles = circleCont.selectAll(".dataCircle")
    .data(filData, function(d){ return d.id})

//EXIT OLD CIRCLES THAT ARE NOT INCLUDED IN NEW DATASET
countryCircles.exit()
    .transition()
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .duration(500)
        .attr("r",0)
        .remove()

//CHECK IF OLD CIRCLES THAT ARE INCLUDED CHANGED THE CRITICAL ATTRIBUTE VALUE (main)
if (countryCircles.attr('main') != countryCircles.data()[0].main) {

    countryCircles
        .attr("main", function(d) {return d.main})
        .attr("id", function(d) {return "circle" + d.id})
        .attr("class","dataCircle")
        .transition()
            .ease(d3.easeLinear)
            .duration(500)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                .attr("r",0)
                .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
                    .attr("r",10)
                    .style("fill", function(d) {
                                            if (d.main === "nodata") {
                                                return "grey"
                                            } else {
                                                return color_data.find(function (y) {
                                                      return y.main === d.main;
                                                  }).color;
                                            }
                                        })

} else {
    countryCircles
        .attr("main", function(d) {return d.main})
        .attr("id", function(d) {return "circle" + d.id})
        .attr("class","dataCircle")
}

//CREATE CIRCLES THAT ARRE NEW IN THE UPDATED DATASET
var newCircle = countryCircles.enter()
   .append("circle")
   .attr("class","dataCircle")
   .attr("cx", getCX)
   .attr("cy", getCY)
   .attr("id", function(d) {return "circle" + d.id})
   .attr("main", function(d) {return d.main})
   .style("cursor","crosshair")
   .attr("r", 0)    
   .transition()
        .delay(500)
        .duration(500)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear)
        .attr("r",10)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
                            if (d.main === "nodata") {
                                return "grey"
                            } else {
                                return color_data.find(function (y) {
                                      return y.main === d.main;
                                  }).color;
                            }
                        })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the solution was somewhat straight forward (and I was blind...).

Instead of having the if statement for a single element, I use the `each()` function and within there check for a change.

```
...
//CHECK IF OLD CIRCLES THAT ARE INCLUDED CHANGED THE CRITICAL ATTRIBUTE VALUE (main)
countryCircles.each(function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this).attr('main') != d3.select(this).data()[0].main) {
    ...
```

Comment: Is there jsfiddle, this is somewhat what I am looking for ?

Comment: what is that attribute main ? are you storing some value to check later ? Please share jsfiddle

Comment: @HarshaVardhan to keep the post simple I concentrated on the code that handles the update pattern. Actually, my original code is more complex and does not include an actual "main" attribute, it was just used to emphasize its importance for the question. I don't have the time to provide a fiddle. But the `main` attribute can be seen as part of a list of objects, retrieved from a database where each object represents a country: `[{country: "Albania", main: "5", ...},{country: "Armenia", main: "3", ...}, ....]`